# Tkinter window not appearing outside of IDLE (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, window, python-idle

I had a college assignment to write a Python program that encrypts a given word using ROT13. I did this successfully, and so as a personal challenge I wanted to create a Tkinter GUI program that used this encryption program.

The code I have below works completely as intended when I run it within the default Python IDE (IDLE), but when I run it by double-clicking on the .py file, it just opens a console window for a split second, and then nothing. What am I doing wrong here? Do I need to pack up the Tkinter window in a different way, or something else?

```
from tkinter import *

def encrypt():
    OldString = v.get()
    NewString = ''

    for letter in OldString:
        OldCode = ord(letter)

        if OldCode < (ord('N')):
            NewCode = (OldCode + 13)
        else:
            NewCode = (OldCode - 13)

        NewChar = chr(NewCode)
        NewString = (NewString + NewChar)

    v.set(NewString)

def decrypt():
    OldString = v.get()
    NewString = ''

    for letter in OldString:
        OldCode = ord(letter)

        if OldCode > (ord('N')):
            NewCode = (OldCode + 13)
        else:
            NewCode = (OldCode - 13)

        NewChar = chr(NewCode)
        NewString = (NewString + NewChar)

    v.set(NewString)

win = Tk()
win.wm_title("ROT13 Encrypter")
win.minsize(150,100)

f = Frame(win)
l = Label(win, text="ROT13 Encrypter", font=('', 12, 'bold'))
v = StringVar()
e = Entry(f, textvariable=v)
b1 = Button(f, text="Encrypt", font=('', 9, 'bold'), command=encrypt)
b2 = Button(f, text="Decrypt", font=('', 9, 'bold'), command=decrypt)

e.pack(pady=5)
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=8, pady=5)
b2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=8, pady=5)

l.pack()
f.pack()
```

Just for reference, I intend to pack up this program using cx_Freeze so that I can run the .exe easily from my USB stick.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Outside of IDLE, you need to call the root window's `mainloop` method at the end of your script:

```
...
b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=8, pady=5)
b2.pack(side=RIGHT, padx=8, pady=5)

l.pack()
f.pack()

###############
win.mainloop()
###############
```

Doing so will kick off the application's main event loop.

Comment: Ah, cheers man, such a simple thing to leave out! I haven't had a lot of time with Tkinter, so I'm still learning everything. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly import Tkinter like:**

```
from Tkinter import *
```

Then the remaining code is work fine.

**At the end call the root window**

`win.mainloop()`

Comment: Your first part is incorrect.  In Python 3.x, which the OP is using, `Tkinter` was renamed `tkinter`.

Comment: Yes you are right, I think @MagickJam may using python 2.7 that's why I asking to put `Tkinker`.Yes, but in python 2.7 tkinter not work. Thanks for the info.